# SQL Server to PostgreSQL - Slow Upload

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Would like to ask about exporting data from SQL Server to postgreSQL. I tried to use an ODBC driver of PG. However, when I am about to upload of 50k to 100k+ rows, the uploading rate is so slow. 1k rows will upload by 30minutes or more.

Tried using the ODBC of PG, the DevArt etc. I have found an OleDB driver which is come from Intellisoft and the uploading rate is totally different. But, it's costly

My question are:

1. Using ODBC, how can I speed up the uploading speed rate?
2. Can I create a .Net app for efficient uploading?

Or do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add the postgreSQL to MS SQL as a linked server and then do the inserts using OPENQUERY. Did you considered about this option ? Have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a .Net app and manature all upload procedure. Now for the upload, you could Use [EntityWorker](https://github.com/AlenToma/EntityWorker.Core) to connect to both databases and upload all your data.

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes for a thousand rows is ridiculously slow.

I would recommend that you start with a linked server in SQL Server for Postgres.  You can start with the documentation on [external links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).